# NSJSONSerialization NSJSONReadingAllowFragments reading

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

In the following code for parsing a JSON, when objects happen to be other than NSArray or NSDictionary, NSJSONReadingAllowFragments is used.

The below code works fine and prints out 32. but if replace 32 by abcd, it outputs to null.
Any idea why its null for a string abcd.

```
NSString *num=@"32";
NSError *error;
NSData *createdData = [num dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id response=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:createdData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response= %@",response);
```

Comment: Remark: If a method fails and you don't know why, and that method has an *error parameter* - why don't you use that parameter to get information about the problem?

Comment: Thanks Martin, i will add that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s because `32` is a valid JSON fragment (a number), but `abcd` is not a valid JSON fragment since all strings must be quoted. Try:

```
NSString *num=@"\"abcd\"";
```

which produces `"abcd"` instead of `abcd`.

(also, bear in mind that the object being returned is not really an `NSDictionary`, so declaring it as `id` makes more sense)

Comment: That was a nice answer, waiting for 3 minutes to pass by so I can tick the answer.

Comment: It does not matter how you declare the variable, so `NSDictionary *responseDictionary` is OK if you expect a dictionary. But verifying that with `isKindOfClass:` would make sense.

Comment: Yes I will add that too. The response that I will get is NSDictionary, but adding a check will save me from a exception if some how it comes out to be other than NSDictionary

Comment: @MartinR It does work at both compile- and run-time, but using `id` and then casting to the correct type after judicious use of `-isKindOfClass:` makes the code clearer, also allowing static typing and analysis.

Comment: @Bavarious I see I have a complex JSON, and using the following code makes things more complex to understand ex: id allFriends=[response objectForKey:@"friends"]; if([allFriends isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ NSDictionary *allFriendsDictionary=(NSDictionary*) allFriends; } . Here allFriends and allFriendsDictionary is quite confusing, so any suggestions on it. There are many dictionary and array in the response.

Comment: @weber67 If you are sure that the JSON parser returns a dictionary, it is okay to use `NSDictionary *` as the data type even if you still send it `-isKindOfClass:` to enforce that assumption. On the other hand, if you are writing something generic that can be either a dictionary or a string as you mentioned in your question, then you should cast it to the correct type if you intend to send it specific `NSDictionary` or `NSString` methods.